# How prevent zoom in mobile using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

To prevent zoom in html you can use `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0"/>` in the header.

How about implement prevent zoom with javascript?

Comment: You will have to catch event and the use `event.preventDefault` to stop default behavior.

Comment: How about you *don't* prevent zoom in mobile? It's *really* annoying when sites do that. (And the browser that I use has a setting that lets me override sites that do.)

Comment: It is for avideo Game there are arrow buttons  if you miss the buttons the Game screen zoom in and lose focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way.

Native:

```
var tag = document.createElement('meta');
tag.name="viewport";
tag.content = "user-scalable=0";
document.head.appendChild(tag);
```

jQuery:

```
$('<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0"/>').appendTo('head');
```